# defining and iterating through array of strings in c

Tags: c

How can I define an array of string in c then iterate with a loop through the items in the array?

So far I have

```
char myStrings[][10] = { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five" };
// do I need to specify the "10" maximum length?
// also does it automatically create a null ending character after the string?

int i = 0;
for( i = 0; i < ; i++)
{
// I need to pass each string to  a function which accepts
// const char *
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When you declare a char sequence with `""`, null terminator is added.

```
char myStrings[][10] = { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five" };

for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(myStrings) / sizeof(myStrings[0]); i++)
{
    fooThatReceivesOneString(myStrings[i]);
}
```

---

**Edit - sizeof()**

sizeof() returns the size of a variable. It doesn't matter if the variable is an int, array or 2d array.

For example, see the following program

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    char myStrings[][10] = { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five" };
    printf("sizeof(myStrings):    %zu\n", sizeof(myStrings));
    printf("sizeof(myStrings[0]): %zu\n", sizeof(myStrings[0]));
    return 0;
}
```

Which outputs (on my machine):

```
sizeof(myStrings):    50
sizeof(myStrings[0]): 10
```

Since each element in the array has the same size (in our case declared to be 10 bytes) we can divide the sizeof the outer array by the sizeof any of its elements to get the number of constituent elements. The simplest option is to just take the first one!

Comment: Works...but care to explain ?

Comment: @OrsirisdeJong - explain which part?

Comment: I don't get the `i < sizeof(myStrings) / sizeof(myStrings[0])` part. How does that give the number of strings in the array ? Does i have to be size_t in that case ? Can i be an int ? I thought sizeof wasn't aware of multidimensional arrays.

Answer (score 11):

```
void loopftn (void)
{
  char *numbers[] = {"One", "Two", "Three", ""}, **n;

  n = numbers;
  while (*n != "") {
    printf ("%s\n",  *n++);
  }
  return;
}
```

1. You don't need to have a maximum length.
2. All strings in C are null-terminated.

Comment: If you remove the last element in the array that is an empty string it leads to segfault.

Comment: Note: Don't remove the empty string at the end of the array.

Comment: I have seen `NULL` used at the last element instead of the empty string. It might help to prevent accidental removal.

Comment: Null is problematic as it is not as defined in K&R. I discussed it with R and he promised to write an errata. You see you can’t count on null being a zero at location zero, as stated in K&R, due to embedded systems and modern practice.

Comment: I don't quite understand why both in your and in the other answer increment work correctly despite they are different: `*n++` vs. `++ptr`. Is it because increment operator (++) takes precedence over the dereference operator (*)?

Comment: I'm incrementing the pointer after the value (*n) is printed, so the deref is binding tighter. When you write ++ptr; you are just incrementing the pointer and you could also say ptr++;  If I wanted to move the pointer before printing the new value,  I think I'd need parens: *(++n).

Answer (score 6):

In C the statement as shown above **n != "" , is illegal at first sight. It compares a pointer with a string. Even *n != "", would compare the pointer of the string with the "" stack string pointer, not the strings. Should use strcmp or compare first character **n=='\0'  or **n==0.
Also +*n increments the character int the pointed string, not the pointer to string...

Here is a good implementation:

Code:

```
static const char* strings[]={"asdf","asdfasdf",0};
const char** ptr = strings;
while(*ptr != 0)
{
   printf("%s \n", *ptr);
   ++ptr;
}
```

Comment: How would be while-loop with **ptr1 and **ptr2 at the same time?

Comment: I have my compiler using as many flags as I can to make it as strict as possible.
Your solution works. The other solution with more upvotes you are mentioning
does not.

Comment: See #2. Also, check that you are getting proper chars.

Comment: Also, it’s ugly to have that zero at the end of a string array; one should try to not write ugly code. You are a writer, with an audience.

Comment: @Engineer It is more confusing to have a "" instead of 0. At least with 0 it is more clear what he is trying to do with the code. With "" I have no idea if that was on purpose or not at first glance.

Comment: The while() loop checks against "" so I think it is more obvious what is happening. There is no need to confuse the issue with NULL, or 0, or whatever other representation you could choose and assume the reader understands your mental gymnastics; it's an array of STRINGS.. The loop ends when it sees an empty string in my version.

Comment: Your and the  other answer have different ways of incrementing the current pointer: `*n++` vs. `++ptr`, but they both work. Why is that? Is it because the increment operator (++) has higher precedence than the dereference operator (*)?

Answer (score 2):

> do I need to specify the "10" maximum length?

Yes, apart from the 1st dimension of the array you need to mention all the subsequent dimensions

> lso does it automatically create a null ending character after the
>   string?

Yes

> I need to pass each string to  a function which accepts const char *

You can pass each string like this:

```
for( i = 0; i < ; i++)
{
  foo(myStrings[i]);
}
```

Also, You can choose between `const char*` and `char*`; since you have declare this as an array it's modifyable; had it been something like

```
const char *mystrings[] = { " ", " "}; // string literal
```

then you must have to pass it as `const char*` because string literals should always be `const char*`

Comment: C'mon, almost the best answer, but you didn't provide an answer to the main question: _how to access the particular string_ :)

Answer (score 1):

ad 1) You need to specify a length

ad 2) Yes, string literals are null-ended.

Inside your for, just call the function with parameter myStrings[i].

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to specify the length, or add a NULL entry as the last entry in your string array. C does not do that automatically for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
int j =0;
while (char myStrings[][j] !='\0'){
  i++;
}
for (i = 0; i < j; i++)    {
  somemethod(myStrings[][i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I always do it that way, seems elegant and easy to me.
You just define an array as usual, without fixed index.
All you have to make sure is to add a single 0 at the end.
Then you can make the shortest TEST case possible and iterate through it with for or while.

Here is an example, it displays a list of options and the fitting help element (in that case the help array needs to be at least as long as the options one.

```
const char *options[]={
    "CAL_MAG_MIN",
    "CAL_MAG_MAX",
    0
    };
const char *help[]={
    "<X,Y,Z>",
    "<X,Y,Z>",
    0
    };

int pos;
for (pos=0;options[pos];pos++)
{
    printf("\t %s %s\n",options[pos],help[pos]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```
int main()
{
  int upp;

  int num;
  char password[20];
  int i;

  printf("Enter a Password (Must include a special char, a number, and an uppercase letter): \n");
  scanf(" %s", password);

  for (i=0;i<strlen(password);i++){
    if (isupper(password[i])){
      upp=1;

    }else if (isdigit(password[i])){
      num=1;
    }
  }if (num==1 && upp==1){
    printf("u may enter");
  }else
  printf("try again");

  return 0;
}
```