# Iterating through const char* array

Tags: c++

I have an really simple example of array of const char's and one function supposed to print them out (iterate through the chosen one). Contrary all my expectations, it's iterating through all of them and not only the one that was passed as argument.

```
#include <iostream>

const char* oranges[] = {
    "ORANGE",
    "RED ORANGE"
};

const char* apples[] = {
    "APPLE"
};

const char* lemons[] = {
    "LEMON"
};

void printFruit(const char** fruit){
    int i =0;
    while (fruit[i] != '\0'){
        std::cout << "---------------------\n";
        std::cout << fruit[i] << "\n";
        i++;
    }
}

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
   printFruit(oranges); 
   return 0;
}
```

The result i would expect is that the function printFruit with oranges given as argument will print ORANGE and RED ORANGE, meanwhile i get printed ALL of the fruits defined (from other arrays), like this:

```
---------------------
ORANGE
---------------------
RED ORANGE
---------------------
APPLE
---------------------
LEMON
```

Sorry for my ignorance but why is this happening ?

Edit: I followed this question: [defining and iterating through array of strings in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6812242/defining-and-iterating-through-array-of-strings-in-c) that is similar to mine.

Comment: why do you expect an array to be 0-terminated?..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are checking that `fruit[i] != '\0'`. That is wrong because `fruit[i]` is a `char *`, not a char. Furthermore, your vectors aren't terminated. You probably wanted to check whether `fruit[i] != 0`, or `*fruit[i] != '\0'`. In the first case, you need to terminate the vectors like this:

```
const char* oranges[] = {
    "ORANGE",
    "RED ORANGE",
    0  // or NULL
};
```

In the second:

```
const char* oranges[] = {
    "ORANGE",
    "RED ORANGE",
    ""
};
```

Comment: Thank you, now my example is working like expected. Still digging into c++ with such simple examples. I'm bit confused when it comes to pointers to pointers (printFruit function argument). Really still can't get why my oranges that are const char* type become const char** in the function argument (so the argument becomes pointer to pointer).

Comment: Your oranges is a `const char *[]`. That's a vector of pointers; not a `const char *`. It's a subtle but big difference: a `const char *` can point to a string, but a `const char *[]` refers to an array of strings!

Answer (score 9):

You are having UB here. Your condition

```
while (fruit[i] != '\0')
```

will never be met because there are no elements that are equal to `\0`.

All the arrays are placed exactly one after another in the memory. Your `i` keeps increasing forever. On `i = 1` you are on the first string in `oranges`. On `i = 2` you are on the second element.

After that, `i` becomes 3. Since right after `oranges`, in your mamory lies the `apples` array, your pointer starts pointing to it and the app prints `APPLE`. On `i = 4` the pointer is on the `lemons` array and the app prints `LEMONS`. After that you effectively go out of your own memory which for me results in a crash.

To fix that you need to explicitly add an empty element into each of the arrays, e.g.

```
const char* oranges[] = {
    "ORANGE",
    "RED ORANGE",
    0
};
```

Comment: And the comparison should be `while ( fruit[i] != NULL )`.  The compiler may not care, but human readers will.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, you'd  be better off knowing exactly how many elements that you're dealing with. The bad news is that a simple array of character pointers won't tell you (it's not a `std::vector`) so you won't be able to discover it in your `printFruit` function.

The good news, however, is that it is available at compile time so you don't have to worry about the overhead of finding it out. The following shows what I mean:

```
void printFruit(const char** fruit, int fruitSize){
    int i =0;
    while (i < fruitSize){
        std::cout << "---------------------\n";
        std::cout << fruit[i] << "\n";
        i++;
    }
}

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
   // The second parameter can be worked out by the compiler.
   printFruit(oranges, sizeof(oranges)/sizeof(const char*) ); 
   return 0;
}
```

Since you're using C++ though, I'd strongly recommend that you use one of the standard collection types such as `vector` as they're much safer when it comes to bounds checking, memory allocation etc.

Comment: Thank you for your response, i really appreciate it. I'm kinda still unexperienced in c++ and somewhat missing the "what goes where" sixth sense. I possibly would go with vectors, but as i diggled around there is really no simple "inline" method to define constant / static vectors (such as those fruits arrays), that remain more or less "portable" possibly under linux / unix sky which i'm mostly focused.

Comment: @cybercow: I believe C++11 might add support for this, I'm sure someone can verify or correct me. Otherwise, you're right: If you want them to be static constants then they'd have to be as above.

Answer (score 1):

```
const char* oranges[] = {
    "ORANGE",
    "RED ORANGE"
};

const char* apples[] = {
    "APPLE"
};

const char* lemons[] = {
    "LEMON"
};
```

in memory will looks somthing like

"ORANGE""RED ORANGE""APPLE""LEMON"

```
while (fruit[i] != '\0'){
    std::cout << "---------------------\n";
    std::cout << fruit[i] << "\n";
    i++;
}
```

will end when you reach the end of "big array" which is "LEMON"

to make your code working you need memory to looks like 
"ORANGE""RED ORANGE"0"APPLE"0"LEMON"0 so

```
   const char* oranges[] = {
        "ORANGE",
        "RED ORANGE",
    0
    };

    const char* apples[] = {
        "APPLE",
    0
    };

    const char* lemons[] = {
        "LEMON"
     ,0
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const char* oranges[] = {
    "ORANGE",
    "RED ORANGE",
    "\0"
};
```

Your arrays are located in memory one after another so it continues printing others because the `while` condition is `false`